# Bash - Simpler and more legible way to check if variable is true or false

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, boolean-logic

In Bash `0` is `true` and any other number is `false`, like in C.

To test if a variable is true I'm currently doing:

```sh
is_on=0

if [ $is_on -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "It's on!"
else
    echo "It's off!"
fi
```

---

I want somethings more simple and readable, so I tried:

This doesn't because `[` always returns `0`:

```sh
is_on=0

if [ $is_on ]; then
    echo "It's on!"
else
    echo "It's off!"
fi
```

This also doesn't because `[[` always returns `0`:

```sh
is_on=0

if [[ $is_on ]]; then
    echo "It's on!"
else
    echo "It's off!"
fi
```

This also doesn't work:

```sh
is_on=0

if [ $is_on -eq true ]; then
    echo "It's on!"
else
    echo "It's off!"
fi
```

This inverses the logic:

```sh
is_on=0

if (( $is_on )); then
    echo "It's on!"
else
    echo "It's off!"  # Prints this!
fi
```

This works, but it's a string comparison:

```sh
is_on=true

if [ $is_on = true ]; then
    echo "It's on!"
else
    echo "It's off!"
fi
```

Is there a simpler and more legible way to check if a variable is `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **interpretation** of a value depends on the **context**. So some facts:

When doing some logic:

- `0` *means* false,
- nonzero *means* true.

When doing some action:

- `0` exit status *means* success,
- nonzero exit status *means* failure.

The `if` body executes when the command is successful. The `if` body executes when command exits with zero exit status.

The exit status of `(( ... ))` arithmetic expansion depends on the *logical value* of the last expression inside. A value of true means success and a value of false means failure (read that twice).

See [man test](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) and inspect `STRING equivalent to -n STRING` part. Also research [bash builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html), [bash shell arithemtic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic), [bash exit status](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html#Exit-Status).

> Is there a simpler and more legible way to check if a variable is true or false?

In a controlled environment I just use the variable value and execute the shell builtins `false` and `true` (that return an exit status of nonzero (failure) and zero (success) respectively):

```
is_on=true
if "$is_on"; then
```

In not controlled environment it's best to compare the strings to be protected against strange user input:

```
is_on="$1"
if [[ "$is_on" = 'true' ]]; then
```

If you wish to handle complicated cases, then write your own logic for it. In bash all variable values are strings, there are no other variable types (well, there are arrays of strings):

```
shopt +extglob
user_boolean_value_to_my_boolean_convention() {
    case "$1" in
    # 0 and 0000000 are false
    +(0)) echo false; ;;
    # any nonzero number or string true is true
    +([0-9])|T|t|[Tt][rR][uU][eE]) echo true; return; ;; 
    # all the rest is false
    *) echo false; ;;
    esac
}
is_on=$(user_boolean_value_to_my_boolean_convention "$1")
if "$is_on"; then
```

Comment: One convenient fact is that plain `[` looks for an empty string; so you can use the convention `if [ "$variable" ]` and set it to empty to mean *false*.